# Add Publisher to EXE visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exe

I made a small c# programm in visual studio, but when my friends try to open it, it shows the *Windows protected your PC* screen, how can I fix that?

Edit: I also tried Signtool, but that didnt change anything

Answer (score 1):

You need to sign your code to avoid this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/signtool
or under the "Signing" tab of the project properties

This normally involves in buying a code signing certificate:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/dashboard/get-a-code-signing-certificate#step-2-buy-a-new-code-signing-certificate

Comment: Is there any way how I can do that for free?

Comment: You could create an installer - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects